# In Pytorch, when transferring to GPU, I get an error "is on CPU, but expected to be on GPU"

Tags: pytorch, gpu

Error example: "Tensor for 'out' is on CPU, Tensor for argument #1 'self' is on CPU, but expected them to be on GPU". I was stuck on the tutorial for classification:

https://pytorch.org/tutorials/beginner/blitz/cifar10_tutorial.html

Note: The code is for regression.

Code is below:

```
class Net(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self, num_features, size_hidden_layer, n_hidden_layer):
        super(Net, self).__init__()
        self.size_hidden_layer = size_hidden_layer
        self.n_hidden_layer = n_hidden_layer
        self.hidden_layers = list()
        self.hidden_layers.append(nn.Linear(num_features, size_hidden_layer))
        for _ in range(n_hidden_layer-1):
            self.hidden_layers.append(nn.Linear(size_hidden_layer, size_hidden_layer))
        self.last_layer = nn.Linear(size_hidden_layer, 1)

    def forward(self, x):
        for i in range(self.n_hidden_layer):
            x = torch.relu(self.hidden_layers[i](x))
        return self.last_layer(x)
```

Answer (score 0):

What does the tutorial section not mention is that the parameters have to be wrapped in order to be read by the GPU. For example, look at `__init__` where normal and neural network layers are wrapped in `nn.Sequential`.

```
class Net(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self, num_features, size_hidden_layer, n_hidden_layer):
        super(Net, self).__init__()
        self.size_hidden_layer = size_hidden_layer
        self.n_hidden_layer = n_hidden_layer
        hidden_layers = list()
        hidden_layers.append(nn.Linear(num_features, size_hidden_layer))
        for _ in range(n_hidden_layer-1):
            hidden_layers.append(nn.Linear(size_hidden_layer, size_hidden_layer))
        self.hidden_layers = nn.Sequential(*hidden_layers)
        self.last_layer = nn.Linear(size_hidden_layer, 1)

    def forward(self, x):
        for i in range(self.n_hidden_layer):
            x = torch.relu(self.hidden_layers[i](x))
        return self.last_layer(x)
```

Comment: That actually has nothing to do with this: the error is related to your tensors being on CPU while your model is on GPU. `size_hidden_layer` and `n_hidden_layer ` are not parameters of your model, *optimization-wise*.

Comment: The error disappeared when I wrapped it with nn.Sequential(), and it was an answer to another thread for similar but another question / error that I lost. So I don't know what do you mean.

Also, what do you mean by size_hidden_layer etc.? I accidentally wrapped them in nn.Parameter thinking that would be better (I am new) but ninja edited it as it caused errors, were you talking about that?

Comment: Apologies, I didn't see you had added `nn.Sequential`, yes it is required to register the layer to your module. As for `size_hidden_layer` and  `n_hidden_layer`, I meant: they are not optimizable parameters of your model (as they don't need to be updated when optimizing your model) as such they do not need to be wrapped in [`nn.Parameter`](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.nn.parameter.Parameter.html).